# Microsoft Project - Custom column shared between task and resource?

Tags: microsoft-project

**Background**

So I have a project I have created in Microsoft project. I have all of my tasks created and resources assigned. What I would like to do is add a column to capture the location to which the task occurs. It seems that there is no column labeled **Location** or anything similar.

**What I have tried**

For this reason I would like to add a column labeled **Location**. I would like for it to be shared between the tasks and resources.

I added the column as **text2** from the options and then gave it a title of **Location**:

[image]

Under Resource Usage I select **text2** from my column choices but nothing is populated:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Perhaps another way to achieve this is if my resource list includes the places (locations). If I do it this way is there a way to add things associated with the locations like address, phone number, etc?

Answer (score 0):

What appears to be task information shown in the Resource Usage view is actually the **assignment** information.

The Text2 field shown is the one from the *assignments*. To complicate things further, there are two sets of "custom" fields at the assignment level--one for tasks and one for resources.

Using a macro, you can copy the task-level data to the assignment-level data.

```
Sub UpdateAssignmentInfo()

    Dim asn As Assignment

    ' transfer data to show in the Resource Usage view
    Dim res As Resource
    For Each res In ActiveProject.Resources
        For Each asn In res.Assignments
            asn.Text2 = asn.Task.Text2
        Next asn
    Next res

    ' transfer data to show in the Task Usage view
    Dim tsk As Task
    For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
        For Each asn In tsk.Assignments
            ' use only ONE of the following:
            ' to show the task's value use
            asn.Text2 = tsk.Text2
            ' to show the resource's value use
            asn.Text2 = asn.Resource.Text2
        Next asn
    Next tsk

End Sub
```

The **first loop** in this code copies the task-level data to the assignment's resource fields (e.g. the fields you see in the Resource Usage view).

The **second loop** copies data to the assignment's task fields (e.g. the fields shown in the Task Usage view). Depending on the need, **choose one of the `asn.Text2 = ...` lines and delete/comment-out the other.** The first one would duplicate the task information while the second one would show the Text2 data from the Resource itself (e.g. from the Resource Sheet view).

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered that fields that are assigned to tasks are not the same fields assigned to resources even if they have the same name.  For example Text2 for a resource is not equal to Text2 for a task.

For this reason the only way to copy between the two sets is through use of VBA.  See below:

```
Public Sub copy_task_location_to_resource_location()


  For r = 1 To ActiveProject.Resources.Count
    'iterate through resources
    ActiveProject.Resources(r).Text1 = ""
    ActiveProject.Resources(r).Text2 = ""
    ActiveProject.Resources(r).Text3 = ""
    ActiveProject.Resources(r).Text4 = ""

        For a = 1 To ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments.Count
          'iterate through assignments
          'match up with correct task
          For t = 1 To ActiveProject.Tasks.Count
            If ActiveProject.Tasks(t) = ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments(a).Task Then
               'copy fields over
               ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments(a).Text3 = ActiveProject.Tasks(t).Text2
               ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments(a).Text2 = Month(ActiveProject.Tasks(t).Start) & "/" & Day(ActiveProject.Tasks(t).Start)
               ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments(a).Text1 = Format(ActiveProject.Tasks(t).Start, "H:mm am/pm")
               ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments(a).Text4 = Format(ActiveProject.Tasks(t).Finish, "H:mm am/pm")
               ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments(a).Notes = ActiveProject.Tasks(t).Notes
               Exit For
            End If
          Next

       Next

  Next


End Sub
```

I loop through the resources available, then the assignments to those resources, then find which task the assignment is. Once I find that link then I can copy over any data I want. The above are just examples.

**The result**

The result is that I can enter in my tasks, and assign the tasks resources, dates, notes, and location:

[image]

Once entered, I can now view my results in two ways. I can see by person, what everyone has to do:

[image]

With the time and date formatting it is very easy to read and very organized

I can also view similarly by task:

[image]

This leads to a very beautiful looking project planner that is easily modified.